# Linux dynamic alias

Tags: linux, alias

I am very new to Linux. I just found the alias command which is very useful as I quite often have to dig through log files

So I need to regularly open text files
they are generally stored in the format
...\somename\somename_yyyymmdd.log

how can I create a dynamic alias that can take the current folder name as input as well as the current date to create a command like?
less somename_20121024.log

Thanks

Comment: This can't be done with symlinks (= alias) only, you have to write a shell script for this (or a script in any other programming language). Have a look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link and here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script

Comment: zshell uses also dynamic aliases, with bash and others it will fill alias variables on logon, with zshell it will load it on call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alias command is for making shortcuts for regularly issued commands. The most commonly used linux shell, `bash`, does not support parameter expansion within aliases, which makes it a little less suitable for your purpose. What you're trying to do is better accomplished using a function. This one is in `bash`:

```
lesslog() {
   local dir=$1
   local mydate=${2:-$(date +%Y%m%d)}
   if [[ -f ${dir}/${dir}_${mydate}.log ]]; then
       less ${dir}/${dir}_${mydate}.log
   else
       echo "Could not find log file: ${dir}/${dir}_${mydate}.log"
   fi
}
```

This function will look for the logfile in the directory passed. If you don't pass in a second parameter, it will default to today's date.

Comment: great, thanks. this looks exactly like what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Bash` you can use [functions](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html) in your `~/.bashrc` for this. For example:

```
function less_log() {
  less log-`date +%Y%m%d`
}
export -f less_log
```

`export -f` means that you [export](http://ss64.com/bash/export.html) a function.

Comment: thanks. those links were pretty helpful as I am very new to this